# How to change order by copying elements with specific attributes first in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to use XLST 1.0 to maintain the hierarchy of the input below, but change the order so that all `termGrp` nodes whose `descrip` nodes have the attribute `@type=Bevorzugt` come before all others.

In my expected output this change can be seen as the term `Immatrikulationsfrist` and is sorted before `Einschreibefrist` in the input file `Einschreibefrist`(sic.) which comes first.

I think the correct way is to use the identity template to start with, but I cannot work out how to sort after that to make sure that elements with a specific attribute are handled first. I've looked at `<xsl:sort>`, but I am just learning and I am not sure how to approach this and would really appreciate some pointers.

**INPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mtf>
    <conceptGrp>
        <concept>371</concept>
        <transacGrp>
            <transac type="origination">
                LookUp Admin
            </transac>
            <date>
                2016-05-12T10:12:39
            </date>
        </transacGrp>
        <transacGrp>
            <transac type="modification">
                LookUp Admin
            </transac>
            <date>
                2016-05-12T10:12:39
            </date>
        </transacGrp>
        <descripGrp>
            <descrip type="Definition">The timespan during which you can enrol in a degree programme.</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
        <descripGrp>
            <descrip type="Status">freigegeben</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
        <languageGrp>
            <language lang="DE" type="German" />
            <descripGrp>
                <descrip type="Context">Nach Ablauf der Immatrikulationsfrist ist es nicht mehr möglich, sich für einen Studiengang einzuschreiben.</descrip>
            </descripGrp>
            <termGrp>
                <term>Einschreibefrist</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Segmentation">Ein-schrei-be-frist</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Part of Speech">Noun</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Gender">f.</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Term Type">Variant</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="origination">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="modification">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
            </termGrp>
            <termGrp>
                <term>Immatrikulationsfrist</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Segmentation">Im-ma-tri-ku-la-ti-ons-frist</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Part of Speech">Noun</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Gender">f.</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Term Type">fullForm</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Bevorzugt">1</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="origination">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="modification">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
            </termGrp>
        </languageGrp>
        <languageGrp>
            <language lang="EN" type="English" />
            <descripGrp>
                <descrip type="Context">Please make sure to transfer the semester fee before the enrolment deadline.</descrip>
            </descripGrp>
            <termGrp>
                <term>enrollment deadline</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Segmentation">en-roll-ment dead-line</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Geographical Usage">AmE</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Part of Speech">Noun</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Term Type">fullForm</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="origination">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="modification">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
            </termGrp>
            <termGrp>
                <term>enrolment deadline</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Segmentation">en-rol-ment dead-line</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Geographical Usage">BrE</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Part of Speech">Noun</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Term Type">fullForm</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="origination">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="modification">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
            </termGrp>
        </languageGrp>
    </conceptGrp>
</mtf>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<mtf>
    <conceptGrp>
        <concept>371</concept>
        <transacGrp>
            <transac type="origination">
                LookUp Admin
            </transac>
            <date>
                2016-05-12T10:12:39
            </date>
        </transacGrp>
        <transacGrp>
            <transac type="modification">
                LookUp Admin
            </transac>
            <date>
                2016-05-12T10:12:39
            </date>
        </transacGrp>
        <descripGrp>
            <descrip type="Definition">The timespan during which you can enrol in a degree programme.</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
        <descripGrp>
            <descrip type="Status">freigegeben</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
        <languageGrp>
            <language lang="DE" type="German" />
            <descripGrp>
                <descrip type="Context">Nach Ablauf der Immatrikulationsfrist ist es nicht mehr möglich, sich für einen Studiengang einzuschreiben.</descrip>
            </descripGrp>
            <termGrp>
                <term>Immatrikulationsfrist</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Segmentation">Im-ma-tri-ku-la-ti-ons-frist</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Part of Speech">Noun</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Gender">f.</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Term Type">fullForm</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Bevorzugt">1</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="origination">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="modification">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
            </termGrp>

            <termGrp>
                <term>Einschreibefrist</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Segmentation">Ein-schrei-be-frist</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Part of Speech">Noun</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Gender">f.</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Term Type">Variant</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="origination">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="modification">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
            </termGrp>

        </languageGrp>
        <languageGrp>
            <language lang="EN" type="English" />
            <descripGrp>
                <descrip type="Context">Please make sure to transfer the semester fee before the enrolment deadline.</descrip>
            </descripGrp>
            <termGrp>
                <term>enrollment deadline</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Segmentation">en-roll-ment dead-line</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Geographical Usage">AmE</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Part of Speech">Noun</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Term Type">fullForm</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="origination">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="modification">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
            </termGrp>
            <termGrp>
                <term>enrolment deadline</term>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Segmentation">en-rol-ment dead-line</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Geographical Usage">BrE</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Part of Speech">Noun</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <descripGrp>
                    <descrip type="Term Type">fullForm</descrip>
                </descripGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="origination">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
                <transacGrp>
                    <transac type="modification">
                        LookUp Admin
                    </transac>
                </transacGrp>
            </termGrp>
        </languageGrp>
    </conceptGrp>
</mtf>
```

Comment: There are no `term` elements that have children in your XML.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this error, I misunderstood the structure of my file and used the terminology incorrectly. I have now edited my original post and I hope it is clearer now what I am trying to achieve - sorry.

Comment: What does your desired output would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="languageGrp">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::termGrp)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="termGrp[descripGrp/descrip/@type='Bevorzugt']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="termGrp[not(descripGrp/descrip/@type='Bevorzugt')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that within a `languageGrp` there are no nodes that come after `termGrp` - otherwise these will be moved to a new position that precedes the `termGrp` nodes.

Comment: Thanks for a working solution and for pointing out potential issues if there are nodes which come after `termGrp`. In my attempt I had matched the `termGrp` in the second template rather than `languageGrp`.